# Question about Mohr's Method procedure

Tags: titration

Just had a quick question on Mohr's method.

In my analytical chemistry course we are finding the concentration of chlorine among several samples. The first step is to add a small amount of silver nitrate is added to the indicator solution and is then filtered. Is this step not superfluous? What is the benefit of
adding a small amount since it is just using up indicator solution?

Comment: Well, the silver nitrate is the thing that reacts - the silver cations, actually - with the chloride ions in solution, so you are titrating with that and not just adding a small amount of it. Then, the excess $\ce{Ag^+}$ reacts with the chromate which turns reddish-brown: you back-out chloride from the amount of $\ce{AgNO_3}$ you added to get to that point. I could see filtering after the chloride is precipitated as $\ce{AgCl}$ in order to recover the silver.

Answer (score 1):

> The first step is to add a small amount of silver nitrate is added to
> the indicator solution and is then filtered. Is this step not
> superfluous?

This step is not unnecessary. This is to teach the concept of a blank titration. Your analyte is absent in the solution in the case of blank titration.
The chromate indicator consumes a very small but measurable amount of silver ions (the titrant, from the buret), so you need to distinguish how much is consumed by the indicator and how much by chloride ions. Record the buret volume, B. Once the blank titration is performed, now you proceed to the sample titration,S. The true volume of silver nitrate is then S-B. This subtraction is only valid, when a fixed amount of indicator is added in Mohr's titration to both solutions.